# How to fetch the latest log events from the CloudWatch API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to fetch the 100 latest log events from CloudWatch using its API (AWS Lambda logs).

I have found 2 solutions:

- [GetLogEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetLogEvents.html): allows to fetch the latest 100 events (using `startFromHead`), but only for a specific stream (which doesn't work with Lambda, I want to read from all streams)
- [FilterLogEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_FilterLogEvents.html): allows to collect from any stream in the log group, but doesn't let us sort logs by date to fetch the latest events

How can I fetch the 100 latest events from a whole log group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [StartQuery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_StartQuery.html) API instead:

```
fields @timestamp, @message | sort @timestamp desc | limit 100
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I understand correctly that this is a "Logs Insights" query and it will result in an additional cost? From [what I see](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/?nc1=h_ls) "Logs Insights queries" are `$0.005/GB of data scanned`. In this case I limit to 100 lines, does that mean that 100 lines are scanned (negligible cost), or there could be much more lines scanned for this query (possibly high cost)?

Comment: Yes if you run that query, only the most recent 100 lines will be scanned (thus negligible cost). But if you add a filter on your query, the scanned volume could be bigger than the result.

Comment: Could you please provide a concrete example? Thanks.